# Post to Wall from tab with insights / counter / statistics

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-wall, facebook-canvas

I am looking for a solution where a user will be visiting a Facebook tab/canvas app where a Share type button will appear.  When they click on the button it will publish to their wall AND that there is a way to track the number of times that it is published on a user's wall.

Is there a solution for this that exists where there could be insights, stats or even a counter after a user clicks to share on their wall?  Looking for a Javascript/PHP solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the feed dialog available in the JavaScript SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

```
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      // do something with "response.post_id" here to save it in your database
      //
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

In the callback, just store the post_id in your database and you can track it perfectly.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks. This may be just what I do.  I would love to see other approaches as well from others....but this is good.  Thanks